# What does the "$#" special parameter mean in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, parameters

I've come across the code

```
if [ $# -eq 1  ]; then
   echo "usage: Phar ~/flashmem ~/archive"
   exit
fi
```

I've never come across `[ $# -eq 1 ];` before and I can't seem to find a meaning. What does it do?

Comment: Unfortunately, the way the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) is written makes it difficult to find things like `$#`, since it's shown without the `$`. So-called "special parameters" like `$*`, `$@`, `$#` and so forth are in [section 3.4.2, Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html).

Comment: It also doesn't help that Google strips symbols even more aggressively than man(1)bash.

Comment: @KeithThompson: use ["entirely on one web page"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) version of Bash manual & the first find for `$#` shows the desired location. ;)

Comment: @MichaelBrux: Looking at the git history, that change (adding `($#)` in front of the description) was made 2014-10-09 in the bash-20140926 snapshot (commit 30595b57d9). The change appeared in release 4.3. Unfortunately the git history doesn't show what changes were made, just names of dated snapshots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$#` returns the number of parameters passed as arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $#
```

Now

```
./testess.sh test1 test2 test3
```

This returns `3`.

```
./testess.sh test1 test2 test3 test4 test5
```

This returns `5`.

So in your code, if `$#` equals the number one (just one argument passed), execute the `echo` command.

Answer (score 1):

It `Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.`

(copied from `man bash`, under [Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)).