# what does "$# -ne 4" mean in bash?

Tags: linux, shell

i am new to shell, I met a code "$# -ne 4". "$#" means the number of command-line arguments that were passed to the shell program, then what does "-ne" mean?

Comment: Another duplicate: [What does the “$#” special parameter mean in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20254838/3266847)

Answer (score 0):

`-ne` in bash denotes 'not equal to'